# Converting a digit to its POSTNET code

Tags: c++, zipcode

I am writing a program that is supposed to take a ZIP code (represented by an `int`) and parse it into its [POSTNET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSTNET) equivalent (represented by a C++ `std::string`) and vice versa. The algorithm to convert a POSTNET code into a ZIP code works fine, but the algorithm to convert a ZIP code into POSTNET does not work right. I have isolated the cause of the problem to be the `getSequence()` function; is there any problem there?

Here's my code:

```
string ZipCode::getBarCode()
{
    string zipCode = itoa(this->zipCode, new char[5], 10);
    string sequences[5];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        sequences[i] = getSequence(zipCode[i] - '0');
    string toReturn = "1";
    for(string &sequence : sequences)
        toReturn += sequence;
    return toReturn + "1";
}

string ZipCode::getSequence(int digit)
{
    if(digit == 0)
        return "11000";
    string toReturn = "00000";
    int values[4] = {7, 4, 2, 1};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        if(digit < values[i])
        {
            toReturn = toReturn.replace(i, 1, "1");
            digit -= values[i];
        }
    if(containsOnlyOne1(toReturn))
        toReturn = toReturn.replace(4, 1, "1");
    return toReturn;
}

bool ZipCode::containsOnlyOne1(std::string str)
{
    int instancesOfOne = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        if(str[i] == '1')
            instancesOfOne++;
    return instancesOfOne == 1;
}
```

Additionally, here are some test cases:

```
ZIP Code        Expected Output                    Actual Output
24060           100101010011100001100110001        111110111101100011110110001
92064           110100001011100001100010011        100000111101100011110111101
11518           100011000110101000011100101        111110111101111011110000001
```

Not sure if this helps, but I am a Java programmer learning C++ for the first time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSTNET contains some information about what they are asking about.  Its a barcode format used by the USPS to encode zip codes for high volume automated mailing.

Comment: @JonnyRo I have added this link into my question; thanks.

Comment: Note that there's no need to assign the return value i.e. `toReturn = toReturn.replace(...)` because `replace` modifies the string in-place.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh, I see. As I said, I'm a Java programmer, and in Java, strings are immutable, so the `replace` method in Java simply *returns* the value while leaving the original string unchanged.

Comment: @gparyani I actually consider it a flaw in the API. A function should either modify in-place, or it should return a modified value, never both. Doing both makes it too easy for unintended bugs to occur in the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
if(digit < values[i])
```

That should be `>=` not `<`.

The biggest hint is what comes next - you subtract `values[i]` from `digit`, which will result in a negative number if the `<` condition is true. That doesn't seem at all like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For readability's sake, it may be best to just hard-code the [POSTNET strings for the digits 0 through 9](http://www.barcodeisland.com/postnet.phtml#Encoding%20Table) (perhaps in a static variable in your `ZipCode` class) and just perform a lookup for the five digits in the zip code.  A minimal example is:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string zip_to_postnet(const std::string& zip)
{
    std::array<std::string,10> lookup{"11000", "00011", "00101", "00110",
                                      "01001", "01010", "01100", "10001",
                                      "10010", "10100"};

    std::string result = "1";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        int digit = zip[i] - '0';
        result += lookup[digit];
    }

    return result + "1";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << zip_to_postnet("24060") << std::endl;
    std::cout << zip_to_postnet("92064") << std::endl;
    std::cout << zip_to_postnet("11518") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

A [demo](http://ideone.com/jcoA9q) passes your three test cases.  (This uses C++11's `std::array`, but you could use a normal array.)  If you are intent on retaining your original algorithm, please say so.

EDIT:  PS, since I see you are using C++11, just a quick note that it is preferable to use something like [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) instead of `itoa` if trying to convert an integer (e.g. a zip code) to string.  (See line 3 of your question's code.)

Comment: The assignment was to write an *algorithm*, not to hard-code the cases.

Comment: Besides, how did you know that I am using C++11?

Comment: Ah, you wrote `for(string &sequence : sequences)` which is a range-based for loop, only available in C++11.  It is a convenient way to iterate over a range.

Comment: When the problem space is small, I concur that the best algorithm hardcodes the constants.

Ex: keycode conversion files.